# 2010 List workflows in Designer 2013 stop publishing

Tags: 2013, workflow, error, publishing, designer

I was building a workflow that contains Approval actions and multiple field changes. It was publishing fine. At some point, when I reached Step 4, it stopped publishing, it didn't publish even after I removed a "problematic" part of the workflow completely. Interesting, then even after I create a simple one-action workflow for the same list - I cannot publish it either. Like something just broke on the server.

When I click "Check for Errors" SP Designer reports "The workflow contains no errors".

I then click "Publish" but the Workflow Error dialog is displayed with the message

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were
>   saved but cannot be run.

Clicking the advanced button reveals more information:

> Could not publish the workflow because the workflow configuration file
>   contains errors.

What should I check and what happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem with SharePoint Designer. Close all tabs. Close all Microsoft Office products. Launch SharePoint Designer in new tab and try.

If it still doesn't work , run MS Office repair and then launch the SharePoint Designer. Also check if you are able to publish from other machine.

IF God is still unhappy, Try creating a simple workflow with a log statement and see if that works. Share Your result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I went through all of them:

Close all Microsoft Office products. Launch SharePoint Designer in new tab and try. - This didn't work in my case.

If it still doesn't work , run MS Office repair and then launch the SharePoint Designer. Also check if you are able to publish from other machine. - Did both. Didn't help.

IF God is still unhappy, Try creating a simple workflow with a log statement and see if that works. Share Your result. - The problem is, I can't publish ANY workflows anymore for this list and other lists as well.

I also tried to clear cache:
Delete all folders in the following directory in local:

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint
>   Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache\

Delete the files in all folders in this directory in local:

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\

And it didn't help.
Still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have also re-installed SPD and then installed back with Service Pack 1.
It didn't resolve the issue.

On a top of everything - I deleted all previously copied IF statements (read somewhere, that they can cause the problem) and re-created them from scratch. - NO RESULT.

I also read, that copying / pasting steps from old WKF to a new one might help - NOT IN MY CASE.

I even considered the worst option ever - to re-create all the WKF WITHOUT COPYING anything (so, Microsoft, what was the point of introducing this possibility, anyway?), but even this looks futile in a light that NONE of my workflows are publishing, even the simplest ones.

Running out of options here...